# Have hyperlinks instead of Buttons in Bot Framework

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

Rather than having the buttons, is there a way to use hyperlinks in bot framework. When the user clicks on the hyperlink, the message should be posted back to the bot.

Most of the cards provide buttons to have this functionality.